# How to get the plugin for a specific task listed on gradle documentation page

Tags: gradle, documentation, gradle-plugin

How do I know which plugin contains the specific task listed on gradle documentation page. For example I look at the doc for `Jar` task on below gradle documentation page

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.html

and I didn't find any reference to the plugin which has this task bundled inside it and I can use that plugin in order to use this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Jar` is not a task, it is a task type. It can be instantiated to create a task, like the Gradle Java Plugin does to provide a task with the name `jar`. There is no direct relationship between a task and a task type. You could even create your own task of type `Jar` in your build script:

```
task myJar(type: Jar) {
    // configure the task
}
```

There is no direct relationship between a task (type) and a plugin, too. Instead, any plugin may instantiate tasks of any type (even multiple ones of the same type). You may even define new task types, either in a plugin or directly in your build script:

```
class MyTaskType extends DefaultTask {
    @TaskAction
    def doSomething() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The task types listed in the documentation are just the task types directly provided by Gradle.

Comment: "is not a task" I don't think this is true since `Jar` extends  `DefaultTask` so it is still a regular task. You give pass in a `type` or class in order to properly cast the closure/action for task configuration.

Comment: Well, a type is not the same as an instance. You cannot speak about the task `Jar`, because there may be multiple tasks of this type. Of course every task of type `Jar` is still a regular task.